# What is the best word-wrapping method?

Tags: php, css, layout, sanitization, word-wrap

I have two questions for you guys:

- Which is the proper way ot word-wrap a user made comment? I mean, I
  know this can be done with CSS but maybe it would be safer doing it
  server-side (with some sort of manipulation of the carriage returns I guess).
  Which is the best way? What does the W3 recommends?
- Also, if I want the text to fit the screen, and to adjust it's length
  to the width of the screen while it's resizing, how do I do that?
  I've seen it many times in many websites but I'm not sure of how that
  works. Is this done with the `wordwrap` PHP function or some style in
  CSS?

Thanks :)

Comment: The W3 would recommend to use CSS, as that's their baby and they want it used as much as possible. But CSS itself will never be aware of line-breaking rules for all languages and just go for the dumb "if this word is too big to fit, then put it on the next line" method. If you want a proper print-style line wrapping, then use a server-side function.

Comment: I think there's even a bigger problem when it comes to CSS word-wrapping, that it only works when the text has spaces in between. If it doesn't, then no word-wrap is performed and thisof course results in a 2 meter long text (which breaks all the layout of the site) ¬¬ that's why I was considering doing it with PHP

Comment: CSS has a break-word option, to force wrapping. But as usual, it's broken in IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

W3 would recommend using CSS I'd imagine. Word wrapping is far easier client side than it is server side. However, the browser should do this for you anyway and you don't need to do anything.

To fit text to screen, just use a **div** or another block object. This will take the width of the screen and the browser will handle the word wrapping for you.

For example

CSS word-wrapping only if you need to force wrapping.

```
div { word-wrap: break-word } 
<div style="word-wrap: break-word">Long content here that will wrap automatically by thte browser, but you can force it with CSS break-word</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use `<pre>`, `\n` won't create a line break in the html code, so `wordwrap` only helps to keep the lines in the source code short so it's easier to read.

Depending on the font used by the browser the characters will be of different length, so it's best to use css for wrapping. I think it's enough to define a width for the container tag (`<div>`) and the browser will do the rest.